# Coda like "CSS Selector List" for sublime

Tags: ide, css-selectors, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Coda looks like an effective text editor however I am on Windows. The splash page for Coda has an animated gif/iframe that shows off Coda, there is a panel that slides out from the right, listing all of the CSS selectors used in order.

[image: capture]

Does Sublime offer said functionality in a package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would like to have the outline of the file.

There is a similar question here: [How to get an outline view in sublime texteditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075317/how-to-get-an-outline-view-in-sublime-texteditor/28950875#28950875)

Comment: Closest thing is CTRL + R thanks, I would love a sidebar that displayed the information all the time though!

Comment: There is a feature request among the replies to the answer above. Don't hesitate to upvote/upvote